# Polymorphism, Data types, and Memory in Java

Tags: java, memory, polymorphism

I have a question regarding Polymorphic definition and initialization. To my understanding, data types are used to reserve a specific amount of memory.

```
Base b = new SubClass();
```

If I have a base class which only has 1 member (int x), and my subclass has an additional member (int y), then how can a variable defined as a Base (4 bytes) contain 2 int members?(8 bytes) Is it because Java dynamically allocates memory?

Comment: *"To my understanding, data types are used to set a variables size in memory"* Not...primarily, no. As a side effect, sort of, but...

Comment: Because what you have defined is the variable of a "Reference" type, which points to location in memory where actual value is stored. You also defined the visible type to be `Base`. See more in [this JLS chapter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html).

Comment: There are **very** few things that we can say, reliably, are the same between Java and C++. I suggest asking a question with only one language tag.

Answer (score 4):

*(This answer is mostly for Java. The main thrust of it should be true for C++ as well, but that's outside my area of expertise.)*

The variable doesn't contain the object. The variable contains an *object reference*, which (as the name implies) is a *reference* to the object, which exists elsewhere in memory:

```
                           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
[b (Base): Ref12315]−−−−−−>| (SubClass instance) |
                           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                           | x (int): 42         |
                           | y (int): 27         |
                           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

There I'm using `Ref12315` as a notional value of an object reference. We never actually see the raw value of an object reference in our code (they're opaque data structures).

That's part of why if we do this:

```
Base c = b;
```

...we don't get a *copy* of the object, just two references to it *(modulo C++ copying semantics that can be applied, I think(?), via operator overloading)*:

```
[b (Base): Ref12315]−−−−+
                        |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                        +−>| (SubClass instance) |
                        |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
[c (Base): Ref12315]−−−−+  | x (int): 42         |
                           | y (int): 27         |
                           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

All object references are the same size, regardless of type. Objects vary in size.

Comment: So because object variables are just references to places in memory, does the reference just assign itself to a memory address, and then as I instantiate the variable, the memory dynamically allocates space?

Comment: @JLem You can only initialize or assign a variable to reference some valid object's place in memory (or the special value `null`). When you instantiate a class (you don't instatiate variables, only classes!), the new instance gets some fresh space in memory for its needs. And when you assign that new instance to a variable, the variable gets a reference to this place.